# xcode wont debug on device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

After yesterday release, i downloaded and installed the new iOS and Xcode.
But now when I try to debug on the device i get a message saying that my version is not recent enough! heres the complete message:

> No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

Can anyone help?

I'm using iOS 7 and Xcode 5 official release, and my subscription at apple is fine and everything else checks just fine...

Comment: In the organizer, does it register your device with a valid Provision?

Comment: do you have ios7 installed on the device ?

Comment: Do you have the GM release of iOS 7? Not one of the betas.

Comment: Have you clicked on "use for development" / "add to portal" in xcode's organizer? you might also need to add your account in the settings to re-download provisioning profiles

Comment: Please add your exact build configurations of Xcode and iOS 7. For example, Xcode 5.0 (5A1413). You can find these in the About sections of the relevant app/device.

Comment: Did you also choose to "Trust This Computer?" when you connected your device?

Comment: @MartinUllrich tks martin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the "use for development" got switched off... i just reactivated it...